# Very slow file transfer rate when copying files to htdocs

Tags: xampp

[image: As you can see the clock symbol on billingnew folder]I recently installed XAMPP on my mac. I am trying to copy the files from Desktop folder to htdocs folder.

The folder I m trying to copy is about 5 MB. But it's taking very long time in copying the files. Also I am observing a lag while trying to edit the files on this folder.

You can see the clock symbol on billingnew folder. 
How can I solve this problem ?

Edit : The **solution** is to **download the correct version of xampp**. I had downloaded the **VM version**.

Comment: Why is this still not fixed?

Comment: I have the non VM version now, not sure what makes something the "right" version. Why would they have the VM version auto download from their site, and everything work perfect except a weird issues with simply writing to a mounted drive. Seems like it could be "fixed" to me, but what do i know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem on my iMac. I could not find a solution to this problem. There is a workaround to bypass this huge delays. Comprise the all files to a zip or rar and in addition copy it to the htdocs folder. Somehow it is not that horrible if you just copy one single file.

Hopefully this bypass can improve your workflow.

[People also discussed this problem in this thread](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=259769&sid=56d1e4688262726ccd40c7381d4fc449)

Otherwise I would use the normal XAMPP-Version. On the official website you can choose the vm version or the non vm version. [Download area for XAMPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPbSf.png)

Comment: Thank you !!! You are a Saviour!!! Fail to understand why apachefriends hints you to go for the VM version that's impossible to use, instead of the 'non-VM' version ....